# selenium to get my current position "location"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping for the following page https://mycurrentlocation.net/ by using selenium in order to retrieve my current position (region name & place name), when I execute this code there is this google page (https://mycurrentlocation.net/ ) which is displayed before displaying the result.

Do you have a solution to offer me so as not to display the page on which I am scraping?

**CODE:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import time
from pprint import pprint

# instantiate a new Nominatim client
app = Nominatim(user_agent="tutorial")

def getLocation():
    #autoriser le naviagateur pour acceder à l'emplacement actuelle par defaut,
    # Si on essaye d'accéder à un site Web : « https://mycurrentlocation.net » via chrome,
    # il demande d'autoriser l'accès à la localisation. La commande « - use-fake-ui-for-media-stream »
    # accordera toutes les autorisations pour l'emplacement, le microphone, etc. automatiquement.
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
    # appelez la page Web https://mycurrentlocation.net/ et attendez 20 secondes que la page se charge.
    timeout = 20
    #Pour chromedriver il faut avoir la meme version que google chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = './chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = './chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options) -> on peut mettre ça a la palce
    driver.get("https://mycurrentlocation.net/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    time.sleep(3)
    #Trouvez le XPath des éléments de latitude et de longitude mentionnés sur la page Web puis copier le nom de la classe qu'on souhaite récupérer
    neighborhood = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="neighborhood"]')
    neighborhood = [x.text for x in neighborhood]
    neighborhood = str(neighborhood[0])

    regionname = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="regionname"]')
    regionname = [x.text for x in regionname]
    regionname = str(regionname[0])

    placename = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="placename"]')
    placename = [x.text for x in placename]
    placename = str(placename[0])

    driver.quit()
    return (neighborhood,regionname,placename)

neighborhood,regionname,placename=getLocation()

print("le résultat est : \n ",
    neighborhood,regionname,placename)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: you have an answer to my question?

Comment: There is no need to ask such questions in the comments; there is a (now deleted) comment posted as an answer claiming that "*I just did run your program and it's working, i don't understand your problem*".

Comment: the problem is that when I execute the code before displaying the desired information in pycharm (such as: name of the place, name of the region) there is the web page of the site to which I am scraping which is poster
is there a way not to display the google page and directly display the result on pycharm

Comment: sorry, bu didn't get your question right, there's no any google page at all

Answer (score 0):

I think u don't want the browser to be seen (if that's the case) you are looking for

headless mode with selenium .

add this this argument to options :

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```